# QIODevice::write : device not open

Tags: c++, qt, exception, qt-creator

I've been trying to build a card game using Qt recently, but I come across a bug which is very weird.

```
QFile file(":/file/02");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite|QIODevice::Truncate);
```

The return value of the second line is false. So when I try to read or write the file, this exception is thrown.
However,the file actually exists and a qrc file in the project writes like this:

```
<qresource prefix="/file">
<file alias="01">data.json</file>
<file alias="02">deck.json</file>
```

I've also run qmake after adding this qrc file, but everything remains the same. How can I fix it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html):

> The Qt resource system is a platform-independent mechanism for storing
>   binary files in the application's executable. This is useful if your
>   application always needs a certain set of files (icons, translation
>   files, etc.) and you don't want to run the risk of losing the files.

As it is part of the resource, the files are **read only**, so if you open it with write permission it will always return false.

In short the files stored in .qrc are static.

Comment: There are always unread docs that explain the problem...Thanks :)